# Explorer.exe switches

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, cmd.exe

Is there a way to open, for example, Wireless Network Connection Status window using `explorer.exe` with some `switch`?

When I open that window manually and trace the process in the Task Manager, it leads me to `explorer.exe`. So I started wondering. It gets annoying if I had to open that window multiple times, manually. Looking for a shortcut. Though not just for Wireless Network Connection Status window. Any other window.

Comment: Which version of Windows is in question?

Comment: @techie007 Using W7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no, it depends on if it is a window or a dialog. The wireless connection status "window" is really a popup dialog, so you can't display it. However some other windows you can go directly to if you [know their GUID](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13591-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-8-a.html), just do `explorer.exe shell:::{...}` for your shortcut and fill in the `...` with the GUID of the window, for example to go directly to my network connections page I could create a shortcut to `explorer.exe shell:::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}`.